# How does one prove (A->B)vC from the premise ~A?

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

Is the premise really enough to prove this?

Comment: You may need to rewrite the premises. The way you wrote them looks either copied wrong or it is very unclear. To ask questions you should be more specific with the rules you ate allowed to use. There are different proof systems not just one. Looks like you must make assumptions to solve your proof. With assumptions many things can be proven.

Comment: Yes, it is.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep!

The Material implication `A->B` is equivalent to `¬AvB`.  So, `¬A` suffices to show that `¬AvB`, and `A->B`, and hence that `(A->B)vC`

Comment: thanks, corrected!